# Postgresql - How to SELECT using a json aggregate function that takes two columns as key: value pair?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Supposing I have something like

| Name | username |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | BestMike99 |
| Someone | DaBest |

What query do I need to run in order to SELECT/return a json like

| json_agg |
| --- |
| {Mike: BestMike99, Someone: Dabest} |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having

```
create table users ("Name" varchar, username varchar);
```

It would be

```
select array_to_json(array_agg( concat('{"',"Name",'": "',username,'"}')::json)) from users;
```

[Working sample here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dJ8gKasTDNmMmL3iFnqy9k/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonb_object_agg()`

```
select jsonb_object_agg(name, username)
from the_table;
```